# How do I create a variable file name with the request nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, request, pipe, response, filenames

The request node module: https://github.com/request/request has an example where it just gets the response and then pipes it into a writable file stream. What if I have a variable file name? For example if the link could be a png or a jpg? How do I pipe AFTER I get the response?

```
request.get('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

For example,

```
request.get(fileURL)
    .on('response', res => {
      let resType = res.headers['content-type'];
      //get the file name based on the content-type
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName); //should use the fileName created in the on('response') callback
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close. You just have to pipe inside that callback:

```
let req = request.get(fileURL)
  .on('response', res => {
      let resType = res.headers['content-type'];
      let fileName = figureOutExtension(resType); //get the file name based on the content-type
      req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create the file in the callback, because the callback is run at the end of this program and the filename is base on resType.